# GroupPrincipal don't work (always null)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Trying to get user list from AD.
Here is the code

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                       "c.magmfc.ru",
                                        DomainLogin,
                                        DomainPassword);


        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,
                                               // IdentityType.Name,
                                                "Domain Users");

        if (grp!=null)
        {

           //lalalala
        }
```

And grp is always null ! Why ?