# C# GroupPrincipal is always null

Tags: c#, ldap, groupprincipal

I'm trying to add a user to an array of Groups in Active Directory. In my Test-Method it is working fine. In my productive Code (same Code) I always get null in `GroupPrincipal`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084036/groupprincipal-dont-work-always-null) had the same unresolved problem.

```
private bool add_user_to_group(string Domain, string BaseDN, string Anmeldename,
    string AdminUser, string AdminPassword, string[] Groups)
{
    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = create_admin_login(Domain, BaseDN, AdminUser, AdminPassword))
        {
            foreach (string Group in Groups)
            {
                using (GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Group))
                {
                    if (gp != null)
                    {
                        gp.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Anmeldename);
                        gp.Save();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Gruppe nicht gefunden, bitte manuell prüfen!", Group);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you please help me and give me a hint, what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to write the code without the using statement, maybe `gp` is deleted to fast. Also I tried to call the group with a type

```
using (GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc,IdentityType.Name, Group))
{
    //...
}
```

or with another type

```
using (GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc,IdentityType.DistinguishedName, GroupInDistinguishedName))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your test method and your production environment? If it works while testing (assuming you use a mockup ldap connection) the issue needs to be in your ldap somewhere. Are you able find the identity manually?

Comment: In my testenvironment I have the same function. I can't find any difference. The only difference is, that in the test environment is only that function and I call it with a button. In the productive Code I have alle the methods for the whole application and I call it in another Method. I testet step by step, I get the right PrincipalContext, I get the right string in the foreach loop. 
I user ActiveDirectory and there are no problems.

Comment: About 8h but I found the problem. In my test environment I fixed the login credentials. In my productive one it was all created dynamically, so the problem was, the BaseDN I created my Adminlogin (PrincipalContext) was OU=something,OU=main,DC=dom,DC=local. But the groups are in OU=main,DC=dom,DC=local.

Comment: Good for you! Sometimes it's the small things :) Glad you fixed your issue @VickaZz